# does cassandra cql support aggregation functions, like group by and order by

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

For example in CQL, 
SELECT * from abc_dimension ORDER BY key ASC;

seems to be not working.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no support for something like group by in CQL. There is some ordering support but only for columns within a row. Columns will already have a natural ordering within a row but you can retrieve the reverse ordering (ASC vs DSC) by using the REVERSED keyword.

See: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/SELECT

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CQL 3  It was released with Cassandra 1.1  This has the ability of doing things like ORDER BY, but only for the second column in a multi-column primary key.  Take a look here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of Cassandra support aggregations within single partition only.